# Show/hide div onclick jquery slowly when i click the asp button its not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to show/hide div slowly using jquery when i click the button. This div will have a result from a database. I want it when it opens, to open in slow motion. I have another problem with the asp button when the div is slided down it returns to slide up again automatic. I think it is from postback. I would appreciate any help.

```js
<script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

   $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function () {
           $("#showdivslowly").slideDown(2000);
       });
   });

</script>
```

```html
<form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div runat="server" id="showdivslowly" style="width:500px; height:200px; background-color:Blue" visible="false">Welcome</div>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server"  Text="Button" />

    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code

```
<script src="script/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=Button1.ClientID%>").click(function () {
            $("#showdivslowly").slideDown(2000);
            return false;
        });
    });
```

```
<div id="showdivslowly" style="width:500px; height:200px; background-color:Blue; display: none;">Welcome</div>
<asp:Button ID="Button1"  runat="server"  Text="Button" />
```

Thanks,
Amit

Comment: Hi, if you are adding runat="server" attribute for div element then use client id of div in script. something like this: $("#<%=showdivslowly.ClientID%>").slideDown(2000);                      And never use visible="false" for the div.